# Scala Spark: How to check if schema dataframe contains another schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, recursion

The goal is to check if a dataframe schema (first schema) contains another schema (second schema), and if not, return all the fields that do not exist in my first schema. We can have a simple or complex schema. I think it would be something like a recursive function.

**Example of complex schema (nested columns)**

```
val structureSchema = new StructType()
.add("name",new StructType()
  .add("firstname",StringType)
  .add("middlename",StringType)
  .add("lastname",StringType))
.add("address",new StructType()
  .add("current",new StructType()
    .add("state",StringType)
    .add("city",StringType)))
```

**Example of schema to find**

```
val structureSchemaToFind = new StructType()
  .add("name",new StructType()
    .add("firstname",StringType)
    .add("middlename",StringType))
  .add("country",new StructType()
    .add("city",StringType))
  .add("age",IntegerType)
```

In this example, it should return : "age" and nested columns (country, city) which doesn't exists in complex schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the `structureSchemaToFind` to find the name of the missing fields in `structureSchema`:

```
scala> val structureSchema = new StructType().add("name",new StructType().add("firstname",StringType).add("middlename",StringType).add("lastname",StringType)).add("address",new StructType().add("current",new StructType().add("state",StringType).add("city",StringType)))
structureSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(name,StructType(StructField(firstname,StringType,true), StructField(middlename,StringType,true), StructField(lastname,StringType,true)),true), StructField(address,StructType(StructField(current,StructType(StructField(state,StringType,true), StructField(city,StringType,true)),true)),true))

scala> val structureSchemaToFind = new StructType().add("name",new StructType().add("firstname",StringType).add("middlename",StringType)).add("country",new StructType().add("city",StringType)).add("age",IntegerType)
structureSchemaToFind: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(name,StructType(StructField(firstname,StringType,true), StructField(middlename,StringType,true)),true), StructField(country,StructType(StructField(city,StringType,true)),true), StructField(age,IntegerType,true))

scala> val missingFields = structureSchemaToFind.fields.map(_.name).filterNot(structureSchema.fields.map(_.name).contains(_))
missingFields: Array[String] = Array(country, age)

scala> structureSchemaToFind.fields.filter(f => missingFields.contains(f.name))
res52: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField] = Array(StructField(country,StructType(StructField(city,StringType,true)),true), StructField(age,IntegerType,true))
```